# Reset dependency property value from binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Say I have a Grid, with a lot of cells on it, and I bind background of this cell to some  property of my data class in a style (actually data class property is type of `Color`, but this is not an issue, because we can use a converter to convert it to a `Brush`),

Now when some condition in my data class is true I want the background to be red, and if not, I want it to be the default value, data may change, so condition may become true and false, and I should fill Background red or default

I know about `Binding.DoNothing` and `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` both are not case, I tried also `Cell.BackgroundProperty.DefaultValue` but it is null.

So Is there any value, that I can return from my bound data property, to force the dependency property to reset its value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a boolean property that is quite convenient as you can use a [`DataTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DataTrigger.aspx) and just bind the value if the property is `true`, that way the property is not always bound.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyCondition}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

If you only have the decision between default and red you do not even need the additional property or any binding at all.

(*Resetting values is not possible in a binding to my knowledge*)

Comment: Good suggestion, but I haven't Boolean property, I have text conditions, that should be parsed and executed for grid row,and depending to this decide which color to apply. BTW row can be of any type, because I want to put this functionality to some core framework that's because I can't have bool in my EntityViewModel

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: You could put in a converter and use a `MultiTrigger` if this condition is dependent on multiple properties.

Comment: not answer to my question, however good advice to use triggers, just I can't explain hole my business logic, and why I can't use triggers, Thanks

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: Maybe i did not quite understand your earlier question, you can trigger on anything, text as well.